# Not able to set NSTimeZone to a required format

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I have a TimeZone as NSString value given as "GMT-09:00".

All I want is to setup my NSTimeZone with this format. I tried but wasn't able to do this. This time may vary every time so i can't set it as static in the method

eg. i can't do this --  timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:(-9*3600).

Also, can I convert the above format (GMT-09:00) into number of seconds anyhow??

**EDIT : I just want to set the time zone to a specific GMT format. It could be anything, GMT-09:00, GMT+05:30, etc.**

If it was a static value I could have used the below method for NSTimeZone.

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:(-9*3600)]];
```

But the value "GMT-09:00" is an NSString. So everytime, I would have to break the string and get the values for Hours and minutes. Is there an easier way?????

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I dont really understand you problem, you want to convert GMT-09:00 to a format that the phone can understand?

Comment: ohh okay, i have updated the question. please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried something like this?

```
NSString *tzStr = @"GMT-09:00";
NSTimeZone *tz = [[NSTimeZone alloc] initWithName:tzStr];
NSLog(@"Tz: %@", tz);
NSLog(@"Offset: %d", [tz secondsFromGMT]);

// Tz: GMT-0900 (GMT-09:00) offset -32400
// Offset: -32400
```

works with `@"GMT+5:30"` too.

```
// Tz: GMT+0530 (GMT+05:30) offset 19800
```

and then just use `[formatter setTimeZone:tz];`

Comment: okay thanks, it worked... Actually the problem was something else only. I had forgot to set the Date format for NSDateFormatter and hence, the date wasn't showing up!

Answer (score 0):

this one is helpful to you. optimized help

```
float offsetSecond = ([[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT] / 3600.0);
```